# why g++ shows "gets()" not declared ,even after including <cstdio>

Tags: c++, string, gcc, g++, geany

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str[30];
    gets(str);
}
```

when i use gets () function compiler gives me the following error

```
error: 'gets' was not declared in this scope
```

i was using G++ with geany ide

please make the solution simple cuz iam a beginner.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["gets() was not declared in this scope" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35250198/gets-was-not-declared-in-this-scope-error)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux we still close it as a duplicate, but we don't delete it. How is this question/answer better than the duplicate? Seems like an exact copy to me.

Comment: My issue with the dupe is they are doing `gets(str);` where `str` is `string str[20]` which will never work.  In this case the code "should" work since the types are right.

Comment: @Ayxan The duplicate question has typos and unrelated problems in the code shown. This one is more focused. Additionally, the answer below seems clearer to me than the ones to the duplicate. Edit : I'm wondering if it's permissible to close the older question as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The advice on meta is to make target the best Q&A.  If that means closing an older question to a newer one, that's fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`gets` was deprecated in C++11 and removed from C++14.  If you are using GCC6.0 or newer then by default it uses C++14 and won't be available.  Instead of using

```
main()
{
    char str[30];
    gets(str);
}
```

use

```
int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::getline(cin, str);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`gets` is an unsafe function and is not supported by the C Standard any more.

Instead use fgets.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    char str[30];

    std::fgets(str, sizeof( str ), stdin );

    str[ std::strcspn( str, "\n" ) ] = '\0';

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scanf() to input string.

```html
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char str[30];
    scanf("%s", str);
}
```